# how to use selected index changed event in multiple listviews in single windows form?

Tags: c#, listview, selectedindexchanged, listview-selector

I am working with a simple address book in which i  have separate lists for companies and persons on a single window form. I have a problem when i selected an item from first listview it shows values for item from second list..i am beginner in programming languages. I also have a single list and a single xml file to save contacts for both listviews. Could some1 help me...? thanx in advance.
i have this code in Selected index changed event

```
  try
  {
       textBox1.Text = contacts[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].FullName;
       textBox2.Text = contacts[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Address1;
       textBox3.Text = contacts[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Address2;                    
       textBox5.Text = contacts[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Phone1;
       textBox6.Text = contacts[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Phone2;
       textBox7.Text = contacts[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Phone3;
       textBox8.Text = contacts[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Email;
       textBox11.Text = contacts[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Website;

   }
   catch { }
```

ad other list have

```
    textBox1.Text = contacts[listView2.SelectedItems[0].Index].FullName;                
     textBox3.Text = contacts[listView2.SelectedItems[0].Index].Address2;
     textBox4.Text = contacts[listView2.SelectedItems[0].Index].MailingAddress;
     textBox5.Text = contacts[listView2.SelectedItems[0].Index].Phone1;                
     textBox8.Text = contacts[listView2.SelectedItems[0].Index].Email;
     textBox11.Text = contacts[listView2.SelectedItems[0].Index].Website;
     textBox9.Text = contacts[listView2.SelectedItems[0].Index].ContactPerson;
     textBox10.Text = contacts[listView2.SelectedItems[0].Index].ContactPhone;
```

(please dont laugh i am just a beginner:))

Comment: isn't it because you are overwriting the value in textbox 1,3,4,5,8,11,9 and 10

Comment: The empty `catch { }` may become a pain in the behind. You may want to `MessageBox.Show()` a message there while you're debugging, so you're informed about any problem you did not expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well both peices of code are pulling from the same contacts array.. which you are accessing by INDEX.. and keyed to the INDEX of the `selected listviewitem`.  That means that when you select the first item in listview1 you will get an `index of ZERO`.. and when you select the first item in listview2 you will get an `index of ZERO`.. effectively giving you the same contacts element.

I would recommend setting the .`Tag property of each listviewitem` as you populate it to the contact that it represents (eg.  `listviewitem item = listview1.items.add(contacts[index].FullName;  item.Tag = contacts[index];` )

Then you can ask for the contact by reference in your selecteditemchanged event:  `contact contact = listview1.selectedItems[0].Tag;`